# Usage WinHttpHandler vs HttpClientHandler for apps written on Net Framework

Tags: asp.net, .net, httpclient

There are at least 2 handlers which we can use in HttpClient for apps written by Net Framework 4.6.1+, i.e.:

- HttpClientHandler (part of Net Framework)
- [WinHttpHandler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler) (supplied
  via Nuget)

There are no articles comparing them by next questions:

- performance comparison
- working with DNS shift (when IPs for DNS FQDN
  is changed)
- connection lease timeout (when HttpClient doesn't
  automatically move to new instance when autoscaling)

Could anyone share your experience of usage **WinHttpHandler**?

Answer (score 5):

**Karel Zikmund** wrote answer on my question, you can see it via next [url](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29945)

> Starting with .NET Core 2.1, the **HttpClientHandler** uses by default **SocketsHttpHandler** - new C# implementation over sockets.
>
> It's key value is consistency across platforms and focus on performance (especially against **CurlHandler** on Linux/Mac).
>
> **WinHttpHandler** is wrapper over winhttp OS component. If you need HTTP/2, it is currently the only option as **SocketsHttpHandler** does not support HTTP/2 yet (see [#23134](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23134)).
>
> DNS changes behave the same behavior on both, however, you can tweak it somewhat via **SocketsHttpHandler.PooledConnectionLifetime**.
>
> DNS TTL is not supported - see [#24257](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24257) and [#11224](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11224). The workaround is to recycle the handler on regular basis. You can also use higher-level wrapper [HttpClientFactory](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory) which does that for you (at least as a motivation).